# Remove then Re-Add option elements from SELECT menu?

Tags: javascript, html

Given the following menu http://jsfiddle.net/pYJPc/ using Javascript, how would I iterate through all options and remove them one by one? then re-add them all. I don't want the select menu itself to be removed at all

Comment: you do mean clone options to preserve default options then remove and re-add them all at the sametime keep the select menu right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it using Vanilla JavaScript [JSFiddle Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/b8Qwu/)

Here is the markup HTML:

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option value='none'>--Select a page--</option>
    <option value="1">W3Schools</option>
    <option value="2">Microsoft</option>
    <option value="3">AltaVista</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<button value='add' id='addbtn' name='addbtn'>add</button>
<button value='delete' id='deletebtn' name='deletebtn'>delete</button>
```

Using `cloneNode` to backup your default select options.  The addOption will add the backup back to your select if there is no options and the deleteOption will delete all options in your select tag:

```
//clone our options to a backup
var myselect = document.getElementById('myselect');
var backup = myselect.cloneNode(true).getElementsByTagName('option');
//add backup back into select
function addOption() {
    if (myselect.options.length == 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < backup.length; i++) {
            myselect.options.add(backup[i].cloneNode(true));
        }
    }
}
//delete all option in select
function deleteOption() {
    while (myselect.options.length != 0) {
        myselect.options.remove(myselect.options.length - 1);
    }
}
//attach click event to btns
document.getElementById('addbtn').onclick = addOption;
document.getElementById('deletebtn').onclick = deleteOption;
```

Turns out in IE cloneNode does not really clone it.  So, we'll have to create our own cloneNode, and change the backup to:

```
var backup = IEcloneNode(myselect).getElementsByTagName('option');

//FOR IE 
//Reference http://brooknovak.wordpress.com/2009/08/23/ies-clonenode-doesnt-actually-clone/
function IEcloneNode(node) {
    // If the node is a text node, then re-create it rather than clone it
    var clone = node.nodeType == 3 ? document.createTextNode(node.nodeValue) : node.cloneNode(false);
    // Recurse
    var child = node.firstChild;
    while(child) {
        clone.appendChild(IEcloneNode(child));
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }

    return clone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML :

```
<select id="menu" onchange="go()">
    <option>--Select a page--</option>
    <option value="1">W3Schools</option>
    <option value="2">Microsoft</option>
    <option value="3">AltaVista</option>
</select>
<input id="remove" type="button" value="remove one" >
<input id="repop" type="button" value="repop">
```

And your JS with jQuery

```
var buffer=new Array();
$("#remove").click(function() {
    buffer.push($("option:first").get(0));
    $("option:first").remove();
});
$("#repop").click(function() {
    $("select").append(buffer);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery loaded:

```
var options = $('#menu').children();
children.remove();
$('#menu').insert(children);
```

Similarly in different libraries as well.

Without a library, you need a little bit more work :)