# Reuse HTML in the same page

Tags: html, asp-classic, combobox, vb6, reusability

I have a page developed in asp (VB6). In my page I have like 500 combobox with the same options and the page is too slow because there is too much HTML (like 28000 lines). 
For every combobox I need to create it and put all the options and the selected item. 
Is it possible to create only one with the options and use in all the others combobox? But I need to avoid the same html for every combobox!

Thank you!

Comment: Show us your code for combobox

Comment: So you mean you will use only 1 combobox and then your selected options will change?

Comment: In my code I create every combobox in a foreach. Foreach element I need to create every combobox with all the options. When you see the generated HTML is too large because for every combobox you have the html for all the combobox with all the options for all combobox. Yes I will need to change the selected options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all selects have the same OPTIONs, what about creating the selects with none options, then dynamically add them when needed? At least, the HTML code will be significantlly smaller, i think it will be also lighter to the browser.

Try something like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <script>
      function showOptions(origin) {
         // do your stuff here
      }
   </script>        
   </head>
<body>
   <select size="1" name="1stItem" onClick="showOptions(this);">    
   </select>
   <select size="1" name="2ndItem" onClick="showOptions(this);">
   </select>
   ...
</body>
</html>
```

Then, add or remove your SELECT's OPTIONS like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5422051/2333537

But when creating your code to "showOptions" function, remember to work with the **origin** reference, so you will be updating the SELECT object that made the call for the function, and no other else.

Good luck!