# Dropdown Menu Values from Database and Update List onChange

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have 2 dropdown menu  . Provinces and Cities. All values from the list comes from database, I don't have problem listing the values in the Provinces because I can query all of them and display like so:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("occ") or die(mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT id, province FROM provinces ORDER BY id ASC ";
$result_province = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()."[".$query."]");
```

and display it:

```
echo "<option value = ''>Choose One</option>"; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_province))
{
  echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">".$row['province']."</option>";
}
```

My problem is that how can I display Cities? Becase there is a relationship.
My table structure is:

```
provinces
  ->id
  ->provinces
```

and I have

```
cities
->id
->city
->provice_id
```

A province my have many cities/town . How can I make it that there's an onChange function on provinces and when I select a province, only those cities will appear in the cities dropdown that belongs to that provice throuh province_id.

Sorry I'm new. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a two ways.
With query preload all cities to JS array, with provice_id as one of keys. And then onchange event can be used on Provice select to populate another Cities select. ( Evry time delete all options from Cities select, and then, for selected Provice add new options from JS array ).

Another option is to have AJAX call onChange which will send provide_id to get_cities.php script, and there you can fetch from DB cities for that provice, and return data in JSON or whatever is good for you. And on success ajax call you regenerate second select

and here is the code ( maybe you'll need to fix a thing or two, but generally should work )

http://jsfiddle.net/ihrg/7L7Rn/1/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeCities(provinceId) {
        var cities = new Array();
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT id, province FROM provinces ORDER BY id ASC ";
        $result_province = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()."[".$query."]");
        while ($row_province = mysql_fetch_array($result_province)) {
            echo 'cities["2"] = [';
            $query = "SELECT id, city FROM cities provice_id'" . $row_province["id"] . "' WHERE ORDER BY id ASC ";
            $result_city = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()."[".$query."]");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_city))
            {
                echo '{"value": "' . $row['id'] . ':", "name":"' . $row['city'] . '"},';
            }
            echo '];';
        }
        ?>
        var citiesSelect = document.getElementById("cities");
        citiesSelect.options.length=0;
        var selectedCities = cities[provinceId];
        for(i=0; i<selectedCities.length; i++) {
            citiesSelect.options[citiesSelect.options.length]=new Option(selectedCities[i].name, selectedCities[i].value)
        };
    }
</script>
<select id="provinces" onchange="changeCities(this.value)">
<?php
$query = "SELECT id, province FROM provinces ORDER BY id ASC ";
$result_province = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()."[".$query."]");
echo "<option value = ''>Choose One</option>"; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_province))
{
    echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">".$row['province']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<select id="cities">
</select>
```

Comment: How can I do it on codes? Sorry :( I'm not yet familiar with javascript :(

Comment: here is link how to remove or add options in JS
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417439/remove-then-re-add-option-elements-from-select-menu
OR
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/selectcontent.shtml

Comment: Sure Thanks. I looked up the linked you gave. It's similar but my problem is that the second dropdown has relationship to the first one. Thank you so much!

Comment: I've updated my answer, and there you have link to jsfiddle, and portion of code from there ( open link and there is everything you need ). Ask if you stuck somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax. in you form make sure they id is form_province and form_city

use this script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var province_id = '';

    $('#form_province').change(function(){

            province_id = $('#form_province').val();
            send_data_ajax();
        }
    );


    function send_data_ajax()
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("form_city").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }

        }

        xmlhttp.open("POST","handle.php",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("province_id=" + province_id);

    }

});

</script>
```

in your handle.php code get the post value from province_id. use this

```
<?php
 $province_id = (!empty($_POST['province_id'])) ? $_POST['province_id'] : ' 1=1 ';

$query = "SELECT * FROM City WHERE province_id = " . $province_id;
$result_city = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()."[".$query."]");

$result_html = "";
$result_html .= "<option value = ''>Choose One</option>"; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_city))
{
  $result_html .= "<option value=".$row['id'].">".$row['city']."</option>";
}

echo $result_html;

?>
```

the result will be set on your form option.

i hope this will be help you.